# Are "what is (something) stand for?" and "how is this happen?" correct?

Tags: questions, auxiliary-verbs

I heard someone saying "**what is (something) stand for?**" and another question format "**how is this happen?**"

Are these questions grammatically correct?

Comment: Did you *hear* or *see* these sentences?

Comment: I heard them in a lecture. do you think I heard them wrong? and there is nothing like this in English? If yes, please let me know the correct format.

Comment: It would have to be "How does this happen?" or "How is this happening?"

Comment: @KateBunting Or probably  "How did this happen?"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably misheard your sentences. They are grammatically incorrect. Both *is* should be *does* since both *stand* and *happen* are verbs, not adjectives or participles.

> What **does** NHL **stand** for?
>   * What **is** NHL **stand** for?

If we turn these two questions into statements, we'll get:

> NHL **stands** for the National Hockey League.
>   * NHL **is stand** for the National Hockey League.

Again, since *stand* is a verb, only the first sentence is correct.

In fast speech, I think *what does* might indeed sound somewhat like *what is* (and vice versa), especially in American English, where a *T* between two vowel sounds is [often pronounced](https://youglish.com/pronounce/what%20is/english/us?) more like a soft *D*.

Comment: Thank you. That was extremely helpful. I always try to do exactly the same, when you turned the question into a statement and it, of course, didn't make sense to me but I was just sure I heard it that way. Anyway, the lecturer accent indeed was American so I most probably misheard it :) thanks again.

Comment: @HendMakky Welcome to ELL. If this answer helped you, then you can reward the answerer by clicking the tick mark on the left. It will turn green, which means you "accept" this answer. You don't have to accept it, but it is a good thing to do when answers are helpful. :)

Comment: @HendMakky You may have heard ***What's** it stand for?*, which in this case expands into *what does*. But there's a good chance you simply misheard *does* as *is* because the t and the d at the end of *what* and the beginning of *does* may melt into a single sound when the speaker is being lazy or when they talk fast (i.e. what this answer says).